# Android display image from network with the exact size

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

I'm using `Universal Image Downloader` to create a lazy loading list view. Until now, I have set `height="200dp"` to my `ImageView`, but I was wondering how can I make the `ImageView` `height` correspond to the actual image `height`.

I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as `Facebook` or `9gag` app, where even the image is not loaded yet, the `ImageView` already has the height.

I'm guessing they send the image size (width and height) along with the entry data, and using that they resize the `ImageView` **before** loading the image, but that's just a guess.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909591/universal-image-loader-get-original-image-size

Comment: I don't think it is the same I want. I want to set the dimensions to my `ImageView` **before** the image is loaded, **not** `onLoadingComplete`

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapcontent For imageview like 
android:layout_height=wrap_content
android:layout_width=wrap_content

Comment: not quite what I want. I want the `ImageView` to have the dimensions setted **BEFORE** the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this method for ur purpose. Method is returnig Rect obj.from which u can get image height width, u can set that height first to imageview and then apply download code.

```
  private Rect getBitmapBounds(Uri uri) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

        bounds.right = options.outWidth;
        bounds.bottom = options.outHeight;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeStream(is);
    }

    return bounds;
}
```

For download image this link have some method as well.. [Follow the link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/gdk/+/0f8a40e4cfdc5f6cd47c22e81f69ed0446067c54/samples/PhotoEditor/src/com/android/photoeditor/BitmapUtils.java)

Comment: didn't help this to u..?